# New variable in pandas conditioned on two variables where one variable transcend multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to add a column `col3` to my data frame `df` with the binary outcome `yes` or `no` .

The issue is that the values in `col3` should be conditioned on `col1` and `col2` in the sense that the outcome will be `yes` if the value for `col2` is also `yes` for all instances of a unique value in `col1`. In case one or more values are `no` in `col2` then the corresponding row in `col3`  should also be `no`.

A simple example of the logic.

```
import pandas as pd
df={"col1": [1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4], "col2": ["yes","no","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","no"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
```

```
   col1 col2
0     1  yes
1     1   no
2     1  yes
3     2   no
4     3  yes
5     3  yes
6     4  yes
7     4   no
```

The desired outcome.

```
df_new
   col1 col2 col3
0     1  yes   no
1     1   no   no
2     1  yes   no
3     2   no   no
4     3  yes  yes
5     3  yes  yes
6     4  yes   no
7     4   no   no
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ordered `CategoricalDtype` to accomplish what you want:

```
cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(['yes', 'no'], ordered=True)
df['col3'] =  df.astype({'col2': cat}).groupby('col1').transform('max').astype(str)
print(df)

# Output
   col1 col2 col3
0     1  yes   no
1     1   no   no
2     1  yes   no
3     2   no   no
4     3  yes  yes
5     3  yes  yes
6     4  yes   no
7     4   no   no
```

The same using lexicographical order (yes < no):

```
df['col3'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform('min')
print(df)

# Output
   col1 col2 col3
0     1  yes   no
1     1   no   no
2     1  yes   no
3     2   no   no
4     3  yes  yes
5     3  yes  yes
6     4  yes   no
7     4   no   no
```

The advantage of `CategoricalDtype` is you have to be explicit in the order of data (The Zen of Python)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
df.assign(col3=df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(
    lambda x: np.where(x.eq('yes').all(), 'yes', 'no')))
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2 col3
0     1  yes   no
1     1   no   no
2     1  yes   no
3     2   no   no
4     3  yes  yes
5     3  yes  yes
6     4  yes   no
7     4   no   no
```